# How to resolve the error of Azure pipeline for Angular app

Tags: angular, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, npm-install

I'm trying to create pipeline of azure for Angular app but for some reason I'm unable to proceed with deployment due to following error
This is my Yaml file

[image]

It is throwing below error:

[image]

My local node and npm version

[image]

Please help

Comment: Are you getting the vulnerabilites only in the pipeline or locally too  when running `npm i`??

Comment: Only when running in pipeline. Locally code is running and compiling with no issues

Comment: Also, when I replace npm install to npm install --legacy-peer-deps in yml file. The pipeline deployment is successful but changes are not reflected

Comment: `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` will work as  you're facing dependency issue. I wonder it worked locally. Are you also using the same node version16 locally ?

Comment: I have attached screenshot of my local node and npm version in question on which project is running. Please check

Comment: Ideally it should work, not sure what exactly we're missing. For now, as a workaround, to proceed with deployment push the `package-lock.json` file and it should work.

Debug the logs and try to figure out the reason

Comment: Please post your log messages as text, not images, that way they can be indexed by search engines which will help others facing the same issue.